# Turn by turn Navigation in native android application mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

I want to add turn by turn navigation into a app i'm building. And i found out that mapbox sdk is good. But i'm having a hard time configuring it. Does anyone have a example code that i can follow on? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [documentation for the Navigation SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview/) includes sample code. If you need more detailed code, I'd start with the [Test App](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/tree/master/navigation/app) in the project repo. It includes a few activities explaining how to use some core elements of the SDK.

Comment: thank you.. I couldn't find the "Test App" repository anywhere. Thanks again